# Dynamic SQL error in Talend

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, talend

I'm learning Talend. I'm trying to connect to a DB and just pull tables from it.
I've managed to create the connection metadata and was able to connect to the SQL Server DB.

However, when I drag&drop the connection into the job (as a tsMSSqlInput) and run the job, I get the following error :

```
Exception in component tMSSqlInput_1

[FATAL]: talend_train.engia_test_0_1.ENGIA_Test - tMSSqlInput_1 An object or 
column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each 
column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases 
defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
java.sql.SQLException: An object or column name is missing or empty. For 
SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, 
look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. 
Change the alias to a valid name.
```

My guess is something wrong with the dynamic query (using context variables) :

```
"SELECT \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_UN,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_TN,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_PK,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_SK,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_FN,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_OV,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_NV,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_ID,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_DT,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.SY_FI_DA,
    \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA.SQL_TIMESTAMP"
+"
   FROM \""+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+"\".CM_AU_TA"
```

Something must be wrong with the double quotes, I'm not sure where or how.

Also, when I try to run the query to get a preview heres what I got : 
[Incorrect Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlELT.png)
Any ideas please ?

Comment: I copied your text into my IDE and it looks like it's correctly quoted, assuming that it's a transcription typo to have FROM on a different line than the +" preceding it. If it were a quoting problem, you would expect a SQL syntax/parsing error, not a column not found. Try substituting concrete values into your string and verify if you still receive the error.

Comment: Did you try without the \" characters ? I usually don't use it , having expressions like  
"SELECT "+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+".CM_AU_TA.AU_TA_UN
   FROM "+context.Engica_Connect_Schema+".CM_AU_TA"

Comment: I tried, the syntax error messages is still there. This query was generated automatically by the way, I didn't write it. So on second thoughts I doubt there's a mistake in this area. I've also tried to pull another table, same thing.

Comment: I should add that the query works when I'm not using the context variables.

Comment: Found it : in the context group there was a "schema" field that remained empty. I thought it was auto-populated. I did it manually and it worked.